# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord - has_many with Custom Join on Aliased Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

**Context:**

- I have three models: `User`, `ProjectUser`, and `Message` .
- `Messages` have a polymorphic join via `item_id` and `item_type` and can belong to either a `User` or a `ProjectUser`
- `Users`  have many `ProjectUsers`

---

**Goal**: In the `ProjectUser`  model, I want to define a `has_many` relationship called `general_messages` to get all `Messages`  that are related to either the `ProjectUser`  OR `ProjectUser.user` . The join would look like this:

```rb
ProjectUser.joins(:user).joins('JOIN messages AS general_messages ON general_messages.item_id IN (project_users.id, users.id)')
```

---

**Note**: I want to be able to join and filter using regular ActiveRecord methods.
I.e. `ProjectUser.joins(:general_messages).where(general_messages: { ...WHERE CLAUSE })`, so it's important that this is achieved by defining a `has_many` relationship

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is all to be tailored for your needs, but there are different things to be done.

Using plain ActiveRecord, I would go for a lambda as a scope argument, to define what is that the relation would do.

The line below has not been tested, but you could use it to play around it and see where you get.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

```
has_many :general_messages, ->(project_user) {
    where(type: 'User', id: project_user.user_id).
    or(type: 'ProjectUser', id: project_user.id)
}, class_name: "Message"
```